# Javascript function to display a number and then delete it won't work

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am attempting to make a simple n-back game (memory game that requires players to watch a string of numbers pop up and then go away and match current numbers with previous numbers a certain number of steps back). I am trying to create a simple function that will generate a random number, add it to a string, display the string, then stop displaying it and reset the string by removing the number from it. After I am able to create this function and have it work, I want to loop it with a for-loop. However, I have spend over an hour just trying to get this function to work correctly to no avail. See code below:

```
var htmlElement = "#numbers-display";



   /*
    This function generates a random number, adds it to a 
   string, then displays the string in an html element, then turns off the 
   display after a delay, then deletes the number from the string.
   */

function displayNumber() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
  var displayNumber = "";
  displayNumber+=randomNumber;
  $("#numbers-display").html(displayNumber);
  window.setTimeout(dump(htmlElement), 2500);
  displayNumber.substr(1);
};

//This function empties the html contents of an element.
function dump(element) {
  $(element).empty();
};
```

Part of my problem is that I can't seem to ever get setTimeout() to work correctly. I really don't know why. For this game I want to do a lot of things after a short delay, but setTimeout never works for me. Anyway, any help with getting this up and running would  be greatly appreciated, since I can't even begin to start building the other parts of this game if I can't even get a string of random numbers to display one after the other. Keep in mind I am a total newbie who still has difficulty accomplishing the most basic things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a few things you want to improve with this code, but to answer your question, `setTimeout` takes a callback and a time (ms) after which the callback should be invoked. You are immediately invoking `dump` and passing in the return value to `setTimeout`.

I have (minimally) edited your code below to achieve the desired behavior.

You may also want to consider that `substr` does not mutate the original string, but rather returns a new string, so your use of it in `displayNumber` has no effect.

```js
var htmlElement = "#numbers-display";



   /*
    This function generates a random number, adds it to a 
   string, then displays the string in an html element, then turns off the 
   display after a delay, then deletes the number from the string.
   */

function displayNumber() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*10);
  var displayNumber = "";
  displayNumber+=randomNumber;
  $("#numbers-display").html(displayNumber);
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    dump(htmlElement);
  }, 2500);
  displayNumber.substr(1);
};

//This function empties the html contents of an element.
function dump(element) {
  $(element).empty();
};

displayNumber();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="numbers-display"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

@Damon's answer is perfectly correct, but if you don't want a verbose function wrap around `dump(htmlElement);`, you can make use of the [bind method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

try:

```
setTimeout(dump.bind(this, htmlElement), 2500);
```

Comment: yep, another option would be to remove the argument from `dump` entirely since `htmlElement` is in scope. Also - I would probably cache the element rather than a string ID, but like I said the code could use a bit more refactoring once it's working as intended :)